# Asignar un array a un elemento de un array bidimensional en java

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional

Hola a todos quiero saber si es posible asignar como valor a un elemento de un array bidimensional de java otro array.
He probado y siempre obtengo un mensaje :

> incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String

Pongo el código se ve claro:

```
String[] a = {"uno", "dos", "tres"};
String[] b = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"};
String[] c = {"1111","2222","33333"};
String[] d = {"xxx","yyyyy","ppppp"};
String[][] x = new String[2][2];

x[0][0] = b[0]; //funciona
x[1] = a;  //funciona yo quiero hacer esto pero en el segundo nivel
x[0][1] = "wwwww";//funciona
//Error incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
x[1][0] = d; 

for(String[] p : x){
    System.out.println("mostramos arrays de arrays");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(p));
}
```

Yo quiero hacer como en la segunda asignación pero en el segundo nivel.

```
x[1] = a;
x[1][0] = d; //Esto es lo que yo quiero
```

¿Porqué en el primer nivel me deja y no en el segundo?

Comment: El primer nivel guarda un arreglo de cadenas en cada posición. El segundo nivel guarda solo  una cadena en cada posición. Si quisieras guardar un arreglo en el segundo nivel tendría que ser algo así `String[][][]`.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dijeron en el comentario, en el segundo nivel solo se almacena un String, por lo que no podes hacer la ultima asignacion.

```
x[0][0] = b[0]; // aca es string = string nada malo hay en esto
x[1] = a;   // aca refeninis uno de los arrays de la matriz(array-bidimensional), y lo igualas a otro array (a) lo cual esta bien, es como si cambiaras toda una fila de una tabla
x[0][1] = "wwwww"; // aca tambien es string = string, pero abajo 
x[1][0] = d; // esto no tiene sentido, decis que un String es igual a un array, x[a][b] es un string y d es un array unidimensional
```

Comment: Entonces  @Lobos si creo un array de String solo puede contener strings no otro array.